# Typescript: Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'null'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use this code:

```
const clearTimer = (e: any) => {
    setTimer(<div></div>);
    if (Ref.current) clearInterval(Ref.current);
    startTimer(e);
    const id = setInterval(() => {
        startTimer(e);
    }, 1000)
    Ref.current = id;
}
```

For `Ref.current = id;` I get this error:

```
(property) MutableRefObject<null>.current: null
Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'null'.
```

And these lines not solved my problem:

```
Ref.current = id.toString();
Ref.current = id ?? '';
```

Comment: It looks like `Ref.current` is typed to only accept the value `null`. So you can't assign `Ref.current` to be a `Timer` right now.
Can you post how `Ref` is initialized? If you can fix how `Ref` is typed such that it is a `MutableRefObject<Timer>`, then you should be able to assign a `Timer` to it.

Comment: this is my code: `const Ref = useRef(null);` I change it to `useRef(MutableRefObject<String>)` but not work yet @DavidShortman

Comment: The value held by `useRef` may be initialized as null, but you can inform it what type it is expected to be set to by providing a generic: `const Ref = useRef<Timer | null>(null);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `useRef` with Typescript, you should provide a generic argument to specify what is the expected type of the held value.

In your case:

```js
// The `current` value is expected to be a `Timer`, and is initialized to `null`
const Ref = useRef<Timer>(null);
```

Then `Ref.current` can be assigned to the result of `setInterval`.

See this article for more info: https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-use-react-useref-with-typescript

Comment: `Timer` don't work. but `useRef<any>(null)` work fine